deshabilitar boton de editar nota de un registro de calificaciones con javascript
agradezco su colaboración de antemano.
El inconveniente que tengo es el siguiente:
lo que pretendo hacer es que se deshabilite o se bloquee el botón de editar notas que se encuentra en una tabla que muestra los registros de estudiantes y sus notas desde una base de datos,
El código javaScript que estoy utilizando es el siguiente; aclarando que funciona, pero solo con el primer registro de la tabla, con los demás registros que aparecen en la tabla no bloquea su respectivo botón. en el código aparece una linea en la variable contenedor que utilizo para mostrar un loader
        window.onload = function(){
              var contenedor = document.getElementById('Contenedor_CargaReport');
               var bloqueoBtnEditar = 
               document.getElementById('btnEditarCalificacion');
               var bloqueoBtnCalificar = document.getElementById('btnCalificar');
               var nota1 = document.getElementById('primeraNota').value;
               var nota2 = document.getElementById('segundaNota').value;
               var nota3 = document.getElementById('terceraNota').value;
               var nota4 = document.getElementById('cuartaNota').value;
               contenedor.style.visibility = 'hidden';
               contenedor.style.opacity = '0';
               if(nota1 == "" & nota2 == "" & nota3 == ""){
                    bloqueoBtnEditar.disabled = true;
               }else {
                   bloqueoBtnCalificar.disabled = true;
               }
       }     
     

adjunto estas imagenes

y esta otra es haciendo clic en el botón editar nota del segundo registro que no debería abrir nada porque en la tabla hay campos sin datos


Necesitas usar clases en lugar de id

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

No entiendo cual es la lógica de deshabilitar ese botón, si la nota no debe ser editada entonces ni siquiera debería aparecer. Eso botón solo debería ser visible para quien tenga el permiso adecuado para ello, con eso te evitarías varios problemas.

La idea es que al cargar la pagina con los resultados si ya tiene notas deshabilitar el botón de calificar y que este habilitado el de editar. Pero si no tiene notas solo este habilitado el de calificar y no el de editar calificación porque no hay notas.

ya intenté cambiando el selector de los elementos a través de los id por las clases, quedando asi

quedando asi:
var bloqueoBtnEditar = document.getElementsByClassName('ButtonCalificar');
var bloqueoBtnCalificar = document.getElementsByClassName('ButtonEditar');
pero asi ya no funciona ni econ el primer registro
los botones tienen los siguientes id y class
<button type="button" class="ButtonCalificar" title="Calificar estudiante" id="btnCalificar"
<button type="button" class="ButtonEditar" title="Editar Calificación" id="btnEditarCalificacion"
tocó mandar el codigo incompleto porque no me deja escribir mucho aquí

Pero eso lo puedes manejar con <inserta tu lenguaje acá> Si no has calificado entonces solo muestras el botón calificar NO EL DE EDITAR. Si ya están todas las notas, entonces solo muestras el botón editar y NO EL DE CALIFICAR. Es más, podrías programar solo un botón que funcione para ambas cosas (dependiendo de la lógica de la tabla) y de como hayas concebido la idea del proceso obviamente

Como se esta generando la tabla? Creo que hay un error de lógica y por eso solo funcionaria con el primer registro porque los id's en este caso NO serian dinámicos ejemplo: cada registro en la tabla debería tener un id tipo "nota1_registro2" pero aquí parece que todos los registros tendrían el id "nota1" por eso al usar el botón siempre se abre el del primer registro y lo mismo para los botones cada uno debe tener un id único o algo que permita identificarlos de manera única para bloquear el que corresponde
